# Scenekit: Model change size when animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scenekit, blender

I use Scenekit to animate a model (created by Blender), but the model changes size when animation (in Blender, it works fine).
https://youtu.be/WCE_sXEyfXU

```
    let sceneView = SCNView(frame: self.view.frame)
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    self.view.addSubview(sceneView)

    let manScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/man.dae", inDirectory: nil, options: nil)
    sceneView.scene = manScene

    let camera = SCNCamera()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(-3.0, 3.0, 3.0)

    let light = SCNLight()
    light.type = SCNLight.LightType.ambient
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = light
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(10, 10, 10)

    manScene!.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    let oneLegAnimation = SCNAnimationPlayer.loadAnimation(fromSceneNamed: "art.scnassets/oneLeg.dae")
    oneLegAnimation.animation.isCumulative = false
    oneLegAnimation.stop()
    manScene!.rootNode.addAnimationPlayer(oneLegAnimation, forKey: "man")
    manScene!.rootNode.animationPlayer(forKey: "man")?.play()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a difference between Blender and Xcode. In the end, i fixed it by add IK bone and a lot of keyframe (every 0,5 second).

Comment: Was your animation playing Ok when you click play button on scene graph of Xcode.